# redirect all except userdir (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a pretty simple problem: redirect all url from a domain except when this url is pointing to a 'userdir':

**Example:**

`http://exemple.com` --> `http://www.exemple.com`

`http://exemple.com/blabla` --> `http://www.exemple.com/blabla`

`http://exemple.com/~blabla` --> no redirection

So far I have this but it does half the work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```